# Blank page in Stores>Configuration>Sales>Tax

Tags: configuration

I have succesfully installed magento 2.3.3 following this guide https://digitalstartup.co.uk/t/how-to-install-magento-2-3-and-build-a-web-server/263#chapter2
Then installed the claue theme with a demo and enabled developer mode. 
Everything works fine only when I try to configure Stores>Configuration>Sales>Tax it shows a blank page. I have already increased my memory_limit to 2G. Any idea how to fix this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Did you find a solution please? I have the same issue